# Programming Language that does not permit XSS, SQL Injection

Tags: programming-languages

Is there yet a programming language that will prevent XSS and SQL Injection.

My thoughts are something that is context aware and will correctly encode when necessary. For example, if a string is used in a call to an SQL function, it is quoted unless you tell it to not be quoted. And if you place the variable into a string that is printed, then context-aware encoding is used, knowing whether the code is found in HTML Attribute, HTML fully-formatted (with non breaking spaces and returns), or CSS, Script.

Does such a language exist? One that

- Encodes by default, unless you say otherwise,
- Includes considerations for different contexts (HTML, Script at least)
- Does all the context-aware stuff at compile time,
- It does not need to compile to bytecode. A popular high-level language will do.

Comment: This would seem to be a misplaced feature in a *language*. Any general purpose language will have to support general purpose string concatenation. The mistake is that people use this to build up strings that are prone to injections of various kinds. The problem has long been solved by using more specialized tools for the job, including prepared statements and template languages.

Comment: Correct. It would have to support unencoded contatenation. The idea is to encode by default, based on whether it is used in an SQL call, or a print to web page call. The programmer would sometimes need the option to turn off encoding. However, I think that template languages is probably the closest thing to a correct answer.

Comment: @deceze: there is more that one way to skin a cat (i.e., work with HTML fragments in a general-purpose programming language). For instance, you could embed an abstract syntax of HTML by representing it as a data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surely take a look at [OPA](http://opalang.org/) and [Ur/Web](http://www.impredicative.com/ur), both of them enforce safety/security (to a varying degree).